# Can we limit the number of DAGs running at any time in Apache Airflow

Tags: workflow, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

Can we limit the number of DAGs running at any time in Apache Airflow ?

We have a limit on resources in the environment . Is there a configuration to limit the no. of DAGs running in Airflow as a whole at a point in time ?

max_active_runs parameter limits run within a DAG

Is it possible that , If one DAG is running , all other scheduled DAGs should wait for the first DAG to complete and then trigger itself sequentially ?

Answer (score 2):

By setting [`parallelism` configuration option](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/configurations-ref.html?highlight=airflow%20cfg#parallelism) in `airflow.cfg`, you can limit the total maximum number of tasks (not DAGs) allowed to run in parallel. Then, by setting the [`dag_concurrency` configuration option](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/configurations-ref.html?highlight=airflow%20cfg#dag-concurrency), you can specify how many tasks can a DAG run in parallel.

For example, setting `parallelism=8` and `dag_concurrency=1` will give you at maximum 8 DAGs running in parallel (with 1 running task each) at any time.

Comment: Using Local Executor :
I had defined parallelism=8 and dag_concurrency=2 
Im expecting 4 DAGs to run with 2 tasks per DAG to run in parallel .
However in the UI , I see 16 tasks in running stage per DAG . 
Is something wrong in my understanding ?